# How to change the icon of a listview item

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have the following markup:

```
<ul id="menu" data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="label"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="label"><a href="#">More</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">FAQs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Terms</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I change the icon of all `label` element from `>` to `+`? I tried:

```
$(".label").buttonMarkup({ icon: "plus" });
```

Which [worked in v1.3.0](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/3eAta/2/) but produces [unexpected results in v1.4.0](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/3eAta/1/).

Comment: updated my answer. Sorry, I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I just realized that you want to change icon for elements with `label` class.

You first need to remove old class that starts with `ui-icon-` and then add `ui-icon-plus`.

```
$(".label a").removeClass(function (i, uiClass) {
  return (uiClass.match(/\bui-icon-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
}).addClass("ui-icon-plus");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jbj8L/)**

---

Using `.buttonMarkup()` isn't correct, it's meant to be used with *anchors* only. Anyway, that function is deprecated and will be removed on 1.5.

The below is the correct way to do changes to *listview* widget.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
  $("#menu").listview({
    icon: "plus"
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EAWD3/)**

Comment: @SalmanA you mean `ui-btn-icon-`? It removes classes starting with `ui-icon-` only.